# React native android 0.19.0 how to add node module dependencies?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I've upgraded my react-native version from 0.17.0 to 0.19.0 and the way dependencies are added for Android seems to have been changed.

Previously I'd update `android/app/build.gradle` with my dependancy, but now it says:

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.grade files
```

So I'm unsure where they actually go, the same with changes to the `MainActivity.java` file.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you're in `android/app/build.gradle` and not `android/build.gradle`?

That looks like the message in `android/build.gradle`.

You should be able to put your dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle`, no problem.

Comment: Thanks you were right, I'm not sure how I got mixed up with that!